# How to create an animated ripple effect on the desktop in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, ripple

I'm trying to create an animated ripple effect on the desktop of OSX. Not just the desktop, actually, but image of the desktop plus any windows on it.

As if the screen was a pond and a stone fell on a given point of it.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this? Any sample source code woud be gratlt appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small code fragment on this page, that describes how the author implemented a water ripple effect on iOS. Contains some development information and a video:
http://fabiensanglard.net/fluide/

**Update:**
Core Image provides a CIRippleTransition (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIRippleTransition - AFAIK this was used by Dashboard < 10.7)

This example uses the CI Transition in combination with Core Animation:
http://theocacao.com/document.page/528

If you combine that with a simple [screenshot](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1741/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011008) you get an image of your desktop & the desired ripple effect.

Comment: I just tried the sample app you mentioned, but precisely when I try to click on an image (to produce the ripple effect), I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. :-P

Comment: Sadly the sample has a lot of memory issues. But Xcode generates a lot of warnings about missing @property attributes. Also the Static Analyzer points out a lot of the memory troubles. To get rid of the crasher you mentioned, set the "retain" attribute for the following properties: CALayer* imageLayer;
CALayer* imageLayerAlternate;

Comment: Thank you very much. Wish I could accept an answer twice! ;-)